# How to design NoSQL database to represent inheritance?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

How would I design my NoSQL database (MongoDB) to represent this hierarchy ?

```
public abstract class Customer {
  Guid Id;
  String Name;
  Decimal Balance;
}

public class VipCustomer: Customer {
  String Address;
  String PhoneNumber;      
}

public class NonVipCustomer: Customer {
  String VisitingReason;
  Int QueueNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a Object Data Mapper like Mongoose to manage your schemas? If so, you might try this extension from GitHub to handle inheritance:

https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend